# Converting UTC 0 to UTC local in SQL. But for two different time zone

Tags: sql

I want **historic date** convert UTC 0 to UTC local in SQL. Like;

- 2012-11-23
- 2013-01-08
- 2014-02-23

But we have 2 different time zone. We use UTC +2 after **last sunday in March** and use UTC +3 after **last sunday October**. I need solution immediately guys. Please help me...

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL? Which time zone are you in which you want to convert to?

Comment: You have entries from multiple time zones or you need to convert them?

Comment: We must use EEST time zone. its mean we use UTC +2 but for daylight saving time , we take one hour back and forth .In October and March.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('your date          ','+your time zone','+time zone you want');
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','+02:00'         ,'+03:00'); // in your case, from +2 to +3
```

See this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)

If you need a dynamic thing, you'll need the timezone of each history (maybe you can store it in a separeted column), so I think you can do something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('your_date_column','local_timezone' ,'time_zone_column');
```

Comment: I need dynamic thing. i have thousand historic entry.

Comment: See what I've changed in my answer. Where do you store the timezone of each registry?

Comment: Sorry, nowhere. System designed before me.

Comment: But how are you gonna find out which timezone is the right one?

Comment: And thats my problem :)